# Operators inheritance

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
class Rectangle
{
protected:
    int a, b;
public:
    Rectangle(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {}
    int area() { return a*b; }
    Rectangle operator+(const Rectangle & other)
    {
        Rectangle temp(0, 0);
        temp.a = a + other.a;
        temp.b = b + other.b;
        return temp;
    }
    void operator=(const Rectangle & other)
    {
        a = other.a;
        b = other.b;
    }
};

class Square : public Rectangle
{
public:
    Square(int a) : Rectangle(a, a) {}
};

int main()
{
    Square s1(3);
    Square s2(1);
    cout << (s1 + s2).area();
    s1 = s1 + s2;
}
```

The `cout << (s1 + s2).area();` is OK but at `s1 = s1 + s2;` compiler gives me an error:

> no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'Square' and 'Rectangle')

Why this line does not work?

Comment: must be `Rectangle & operator=(const Rectangle & other)`

Comment: @bruno How will that solve the issue, that is described?

Comment: I was not clear; the signature is not the right one for rectangle, and it is needed to also define the operator in Square, there is no inheriting for operator

Comment: @bruno That has nothing to do with the problem, and OP's code is valid but unexpected.

Comment: Note that it is generally *not correct* to model a square as inheriting from a rectangle. Such an inheritance chain violates the [Liskov substitution principle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59006/1968).

Comment: Do you really want to be able to write `Square s; ... s = Rectangle(1,1000);`?

Comment: @molbdnilo it is not valid, it does not allow a sequence of assignment a = b = ...

Comment: @bruno It is perfectly valid as long as you don't do that. That's a convention, not a rule.

Comment: @molbdnilo for your previous remark you are 100% right

Comment: Assignment is not the only problem; `Rectangle(1,1)` is a square `Rectangle`, but it's not a `Square`. Thus, you can have square rectangles that are not squares, and you can have squares that are not square rectangle. I think the only sensible way to model this is to make "being square" a property of rectangles instead of making squares a separate type.

Comment: To augment @molbdnilo 's suggestion, you can still declare `Rectangle square(int a) { return Rectangle(a, a); }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't provide an assignment operator, a compiler [will declare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment#Implicitly-declared_copy_assignment_operator) one for you. Here, a compiler generates `Square::operator=(const Square&)`. Assignment operator from `Rectangle` gets hidden by this operator. You can bring `Rectangle::operator=` into the scope with [`using` declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration):

```
class Square : public Rectangle
{
public:
    using Rectangle::operator=;

    // ...
};
```

Now the code compiles, but it is flawed. As noted in comments by Konrad Rudolph, Jarod42, and molbdnilo, deriving `Square` from `Rectangle` is logically wrong, as it [violates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56860) the [Liskov's substitution principle](https://web.archive.org/web/20150905081111/http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/lsp.pdf). You can now assign a `Rectangle` to a `Square`, and such an assignment doesn't make sense.

Comment: Which is logical wrong, `Rectangle r(1, 3); Sqaure s(1); s = r;`... with a square, not square.

Comment: If I would create base class Shape and inherit Square from the Shape, would it be sensible to use Shape's assignment operator in a Square class? Or using operator= of the base class in derived class is bad idea at all?

Comment: @michalt38, in the general case it is not a bad idea. Sometimes that's exactly what you need.